# I have my code for an assignment. I don't know understand how to fix the bug. I get a TypeError

Tags: python-3.x

import  random

class PlayingCard():
def **init**(self,card_value,suit):

```
    if value in '2345678910JQKA':
        self.rank = str(card_value)
    else:
        print('Invalid rank!')
        raise Exception('Invalid rank!')
        

    self.rank = str(value)
    if suit in '♥♦♣♠':
        self.suit = suit
    else:
        print('Invalid suit!')
        raise Exception('Invalid suit!')

def get_rank(self):
    return self.rank

def get_suit(self):
    return self.suit
def __repr__(self):
    return self.rank+" of " +self.suit
```

class Deck():

```
ranks=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,'J','Q','K','A']
suits=['♥','♦','♣','♠']
deck_cards=[]


def __init__(self,suit):
    for rank in Deck.ranks:
        for suit in Deck.suits:
            card=PlayingCard(rank,suit)
            Deck.deck_cards.append(card)
            
    self.cards=[]
    for card in Deck.deck_cards:
        if card.get_suit()==suit:
            self.cards.append(card)

def shuffle_deck(self):
    random.shuffle(Deck.deck_cards)

def deal_card(self,card_count):
    deal_cards=[]
    
    if card_count<=len(self.cards):
        deal_cards=random.sample(self.cards,card_count)
        for card in deal_cards:
            self.cards.remove(card)
            
        deal_card_str = ""
        for card in deal_cards:
            deal_card_str += card.__str__()+","
        print(deal_card_str[:-2])
        
    else:
        print('Cannot deal '+str(card_count)+' cards. The deck only has '
              +str(len(self.cards))+' cards left!')

def __str__(self):
    full_deck =''
    for card in Deck.deck_cards:
        full_deck += card.__str__()+","
    return full_deck[:-2]
```

deck1 = Deck()
print(deck1.cards)

---

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
72
73
---> 74 deck1 = Deck()
75 print(deck1.cards)
76

TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'suit'

Answer (score 0):

The constructor for class Deck doesn't need a `suit` argument, you have already defined it above. What you perhaps wanted to do is remove the argument:

```
def __init__(self)
```